# Chicken Scheme: Does module procedures only use procedures internal to the module?

Tags: module, scheme, chicken-scheme

Assume I have the following two modules:

```
(module mod1 (func2)
  (define (func1) ...)
  (define (func2) ... (func1) ...))

(module mod2 ()
  (import (only mod1 func2))
  (define (func1) ...)
  (define (func3) ... (func2) ...))
```

Does the call to `func2` in `func3` use `mod2`'s version of `func1` or `mod1`'s version?

Comment: Why not just try it and see what happens?

Comment: I just did. It runs `mod1`'s version. Is there a way I can make it run `mod2`'s version?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to pass `func1` to `func2` somehow.  Either as an argument, or through a SRFI-39 parameter that `mod1` exports:

```
(module mod1 (func2)
  (define (func1) ...)
  (define the-func (make-parameter func1)) ; defaults to our version
  (define (func2) ... (let ((func1 (the-func)) (func1)) ...))

(module mod2 ()
  (import (only mod1 func2))
  (define (func1) ...)
  (define (func3) ... (parameterize ((the-func func1)) (func2)) ...))
```